# How to make an noncontiguous range of cells work for every cell referenced

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have a noncontiguous range and I want whatever the user writes in each cell in the range to show up in a column in a table I made. In the first column of my table I'm having the program number each generated entry in the table when the user adds a value in one of the specified cells all the way up to 18. I renamed each cell in the range to be "Space_ (some number)". Even though I have written in three of the specified cells, my table only shows me the first value in the first specified cell.

[image]

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub test2()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Integer
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ws.Range("Space_7, Space_10, Space_13, Space_16, Space_19, Space_22, Space_25, Space_28, Space_31, Space_34, Space_37, Space_40, Space_53, Space_56, Space_59, Space_62, Space_65, Space_68")


ws.Range("A13:A31,B13:B31").ClearContents

For i = 1 To 18

If Not IsEmpty("rng") Then
ws.Range("A12").Offset(1).Value = i
End If
Exit For
Next i

If Not IsEmpty("rng") Then
    ws.Range("B12").Offset(1).Value = rng.Value
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `rng` shouldn't be in quotes as it's a range variable, not a string, but in any case you have defined it as the whole range of cells so you need to loop through each area. You are also exiting the loop for reasons I can't fathom (and would be overwriting even if you weren't as your offsets never change).

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure your for loop is iterating through all the areas in `rng` as its currently specfied, similarly your `offset` are all only 1 so only the top row of your table would get written to. I'd suggest your foor loop is declared `For i =1 to rng.cells.count` then check the content of that cell with `Len(rng.Cells(i).Text)>0` or similar and write out to the table with `ws.Range("A12").offset(i).value = rngCells(i).Text`

Comment: Also, I strongly recommend using breakpoints and F8 to step through your code at runtime. That way you can easily find most of your code problems right away, like the offset being static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple things here - Instead of trying to put all your named ranges into a `Range`, put them individually in an `Array` and cycle through them - If they're not blank, put the value into the cell.

Your `.Offset` is always going 1 below row 12, so that's why you're only seeing one row of data.

```
Sub test2()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim rngarray As Variant

rngarray = Array("Space_7", "Space_10", "Space_13", "Space_16", "Space_19", "Space_22", "Space_25", "Space_28", "Space_31", "Space_34", "Space_37", "Space_40", "Space_53", "Space_56", "Space_59", "Space_62", "Space_65", "Space_68")
j = 12

ws.Range("A13:B31").ClearContents

For i = 0 To UBound(rngarray)

    If ws.Range(rngarray(i)).Value <> "" Then
        ws.Range("A12").Offset(j - 11).Value = i + 1
        ws.Range("B12").Offset(j - 11).Value = ws.Range(rngarray(i)).Value
        j = j + 1
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 6):

This should address the various issues I mentioned in my comment:

```
Sub test2()

Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim i As Long
Dim rng As Range, r As Range

With ws
    Set rng = .Range("Space_7, Space_10, Space_13, Space_16, Space_19, Space_22, Space_25, Space_28, Space_31, Space_34, Space_37, Space_40, Space_53, Space_56, Space_59, Space_62, Space_65, Space_68")
    .Range("A13:B31").ClearContents
    For Each r In rng.Areas
        If Not IsEmpty(r) Then
            .Range("A13").Offset(i).Value = i + 1
            .Range("B13").Offset(i).Value = r.Value
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next r
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: No need for the `i - 1`, should just be `i` as his data starts in row 13 :) - but nice solution, I've never used `.Areas` before.

Comment: But there is an issue where if there's a blank space in the range, the data isn't being shifted up - it's leaving a blank row.

Comment: Thanks @dwirony, what would I do without you, amended above.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go as follows:

```
Sub test2()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("A13:A31,B13:B31").ClearContents

        Set rng = .Range("Space_7, Space_10, Space_13, Space_16, Space_19, Space_22, Space_25, Space_28, Space_31, Space_34, Space_37, Space_40, Space_53, Space_56, Space_59, Space_62, Space_65, Space_68")

        For Each cell In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Areas
            ws.Range("A12:B12").Offset(i).Value = Array(i + 1, cell(1, 1).Value)
            i = i + 1
        Next
    End With    
End Sub
```